# Insert rows into database table from pairs of html form elements

Tags: php, forms, loops, post, sql-insert

I have a dynamic form with repeatable input fields. When the form is submitted, the receiving PHP script is designed to insert pairs of values as new rows in the database. The trouble is that the `$_POST['submit']` element is executing an extra/unwanted INSERT query.

This is the foreach loop, (sql secure not included)

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $nearest = $db->prepare('insert into nearest set place=?, distance=?');
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($_POST as $val) {
        $place = $_POST['place'][$i];
        $distance = $_POST['distance'][$i];
        $nearest->execute([$place, $distance]);
        $i++;
    }
}
```

This loop inserted '$_POST' values and inserted empty row.

Comment: Wait... What are you doing in your loop? Your not using the $val.

Comment: i have a form with two input. But this inputs dynamic with jquery like add and remove. When i submit form place and distance inserted succesful but adding empty row.

Comment: See my edit, I don't think you should use a foreach. I think a for loop is what you need

Comment: It would be nice to see some of the rendered form.

Comment: Relevant: [Simplify hardcoded repeating fields in an HTML form to be D.R.Y. and insert submission payload into database](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63431834/2943403)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep the loop you can use array_slice to not include the last item in the loop.
Array_slice will take items from 0 (not literal, but the first item) to second to last (-1).
http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php

EDIT; I think you need a for loop to loop the count of "place".

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  $nearest= $db -> prepare('insert into nearest set place=?, distance=?');
  for($i=0; $i< count($_POST['place']; $i++){
      $place = $_POST['place'][$i];
      $distance= $_POST['distance'][$i];
      $nearest-> execute([$place , $distance]);
      $i++;
  }
}
```

example: https://3v4l.org/F47ui

Comment: still insert 'submit' value. :/

Comment: As I posted in your questions comments what are you doing, you are supposed to use $val. Var_dump the array in your question

Comment: I'm edited this " for($i=0; $i< count($_POST); $i++) " and worked. Thank you very much Andreas! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply remove your `submit` key from `$_POST` prior doing your loop with just regular `unset()`. But this is bad approach. What I'd rather recommend doing instead is to "isolate" your data, and instead of this:

```
<input name="distance" ... >
```

make all your imputs like this:

```
<input name="data[distance]" ... >
```

then you just need to loop over "data" (name as you like) array:

```
foreach($_POST['data'] as val)
```

Also, resist from removing last element in blind, because it's based on false assumption that this is always your "submit" element. What if you add more submit buttons to the form? or the order will change?

Comment: its look easy but $_POST['data'] return empty. Anyway andreas's code working for me. Thank you.

Comment: Have you changed your `<input>`? Check what `print_r($_POST);` lists.